# What's the lifetime of the excited state when you shine light on molecules?

Tags: photons, radiation, spectroscopy, photoelectric-effect, molecules

Let's say, when x-ray hits a molecule, an electron from an inner shell absorbs the energy and flies away, so there's a hole waiting for an electron to come down and fill it. How long does this hole last? I know its lifetime may depend on the species of the molecule, but is there a general value for all small molecules, like a nanosecond? Or could you show me a specific way to calculate the lifetimes of excited states?

Comment: As a general tip - if you start to get interested in excited states, lifetime of carriers (electron and holes for instance) - you really need to go beyond the very simplified "shell" structure that you refer to - read up on orbitals and what the shrödinger equation actually does.

Answer (score 6):

Core-hole lifetimes have been tabulated by [Krause and Oliver](https://srd.nist.gov/JPCRD/jpcrd137.pdf). The widths there are given as the life-time broadening in eV. The time is then given by the Heisenberg uncertainty relation. A [calculator page on Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/parlif.html) gives 0.66 femtosecond for a 1 eV linewidth.

Core-hole decay may take more time than what it takes for a molecule to fly apart. I wrote [an article](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.466346) about a dissociative core-excited state of the oxygen molecule, where the spectrum shows evidence of free-atom-like Auger lines.

Comment: By core-hole excitations, I imagine you mean excited states of the neutral molecule, where the inner-shell electron stays around instead of flying away? It's also a relevant situation but OP should keep in mind it's not quite what they originally specified.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The core-hole lifetime is hardly affected by an electron more or less. My point was that the core-hole lifetime may be on the same order of magnitude as the atomic motion.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, I've just read all the links you provide - they're indeed helpful. I'm more interested in molecules than atoms, so I'd like to see if there's any experimental data showing lifetimes of core-holes in small molecules...your paper about O2 is a good example! I'd like to see more data like that! I'm trying hard to google, but can hardly find data like that

Comment: @Uh-Oh Happy to be of help. I have not really followed the field, but there was a nice review by Morin and Nenner and if you google their names together with "ultrafast" you will find recent stuff.  It is interesting to contrast the time evolution of the nuclear wave function with calculations in the energy domain.

Comment: @Pieter - Good explanation and links!

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't really a one-size-fits-all timescale. The lifetime of excited states can vary wildly from molecule to molecule and between different excited states of the same molecule.

For single electronic excitations, a good rule of thumb is about a nanosecond, but some metastable states (at least in atoms) can last all the way up to millisecond or multi-second ranges.

However, the specific process you described isn't really an excited state - it's an [Auger process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auger_effect), which is enacted by the Coulomb interaction between the different configurations, instead of a dipole coupling (which is generally *much* weaker). Auger decays are typically blazingly fast, normally clocking in between a few picoseconds and a few femtoseconds, depending on the system.

And, while we're here: the measurement of Auger decay lifetimes in real time is a current and active research field. Good keywords to search for are time-resolved Auger decay and attosecond transient absorption spectroscopy, to get recent literature that probes this area.

Comment: Thanks Emilio. I didn't know there's another way to fill the core hole made by x-ray than Auger process (I'm not a physicist, so I know little about this). If the hole is filled by an electron through another process (dipole coupling?), how long does the hole exist? Is it also a few ps to a few fs? What's the keyword to search that?

Comment: If Auger processes are available, then they will be the fastest by far. However, if the initial ionization does not leave an ion that's energetic enough (say, by removing an electron which isn't deep enough) then Auger processes are forbidden, and the excess energy will be radiated away as a photon in a nanosecond-ish timescale.

Answer (score 0):

The excited state lifetime varies a lot. Typically ns range for fluorescent molecules

Comment: Hi Frederick, welcome to PSE! This answer would improve a lot if you were to include a reference. In any case, thanks!